# Migration script name as a placeholder?

Tags: flyway

Is there a kind of default placeholder (like ${flyway:defaultSchema} or ${flyway:timestamp} for example) that is populated by flyway with the current sql migration script name before each migration run?
I want to use the file name with the help of a placeholder in a sql statement (for internal audit processes - the file name of a migration script contains, among other things, an internal ticket number) of a callback script (beforeMigrate or beforeEachMigrate) which, in order to be able to assign it (for internal audit processes), is placed within the same session as the actual migration script (which is the case with callback scripts, as far as I know).
Adjusting the sql migration script name manually in a custom placeholder inside the configfile (as a workaround) before each execution is quite cumbersome.

Comment: What script name are you modifying and why?

Comment: I don't want to modify it, I just want to get the script name before each migration and pass it to a callback script using a placeholder.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the script name?

Comment: I have modified my entry above to answer your question. I hope it will be clear
.

Comment: Currently there is not a placeholder for this. I would suggest you make an issue on https://github.com/flyway/flyway asking for this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have no experience with github. but isn't my request more a change request than an issue?

Comment: I have posted my first GitHub issue. Hope that it is handled as a change request in some way. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned (see comments to my question above) this default placeholder, which could be filled by Flyway before each migration, does not exist yet. I hope that this little feature will be implemented in a future Flyway version.

Answer (score 0):

fyi: as it looks, my change was implemented and the feature will be available in one of the next flyway versions:
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2914